# Updating line of a file if array element matches text box

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a method which currently reads all lines of a directory file (3 fields per line) and updates a directory array with a record of text box entries if the extension code entered matches an extension code field in the file.

I had the updated directory array displaying to a list view, as soon as I attempted to update the directory file with the updated array, it all went downhill! Edit to clarify: with the latest version of the code below, the array no longer displays to the list view, and the file is not updated. No errors are thrown.

```
public void updateName()
    {
        int count = 0;
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(directoryFile);

        // Set size of directory array equal to number of lines in file
        int lineCount = lineCounter();
        directory = new record[lineCount];

        record currentRecord = new record();

        // Iterate through each line in file
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            // Split current line into three fields
            string[] fields = line.Split(',');

            // Save current line as new record with surname, forename and extCode fields
            currentRecord.surname = fields[0];
            currentRecord.forename = fields[1];
            currentRecord.extCode = Convert.ToInt32(fields[2]);

            // If extension code in current record matches text box entry
            if (Convert.ToInt32(fields[2]) == Convert.ToInt32(txtExtCode.Text))
            {
                // Change surname and forname fields to match text box entries
                currentRecord.surname = txtForename.Text;
                currentRecord.forename = txtSurname.Text;

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(directoryFile))
                {
                    for (int currentLine = 1; currentLine <= lines.Length; ++currentLine)
                    {
                        if (currentLine == count)
                            writer.WriteLine(currentRecord);
                        else
                            writer.WriteLine(lines[currentLine - 1]);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Save currentRecord as next element in directory array, then increment
            directory[count] = currentRecord;
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should explain what `it all went downhill!` means because it is not clear what problem we need to solve

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp You're right, thanks, I've edited to clarify

Comment: @DourHighArch No errors are thrown at the moment, which I suppose means I'm close, but I've spent 24hrs+ trying different suggestions from similar SE threads and still stumped as to how to write my array to the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `linecounter()`. The number of lines is `lines.Length`.
But why do you need this `directory` array? You are filling it, but you are not using it anywhere.

Another major problem is that you are creating a `StreamWriter` inside the `foreach` loop. You should open the file before the loop and close it after the loop to make it work.
Also, you are mixing writing `currentRecord` which is of type `record` and writing lines of type string to the output file. This cannot work.

You are also putting `txtForename.Text` into `currentRecord.surname` instead of `currentRecord.forename` and vice versa.

I suggest to first apply the change in the `lines` array and then to write this `lines` array back to to file with `File.WriteAllLines` which is the symmetric operation to `File.ReadAllLines`.

I'm applying the change directly to `fields` array, so that I can convert it back to a string with `String.Join` (it is the symmetric operation to `String.Split`).

```
public void updateName()
{
    // Do this conversion before the loop. We need to do it only once.
    int selectedCode = Convert.ToInt32(txtExtCode.Text);

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(directoryFile);
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        // Split current line into three fields
        string[] fields = lines[i].Split(',');

        int extCode = Convert.ToInt32(fields[2]);
        if (extCode == selectedCode)
        {
            fields[0] = txtSurname.Text;
            fields[1] = txtForename.Text;
            lines[i] = String.Join(",", fields);

            // If the extension code is unique, leave the for-loop
            break;
        }
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(directoryFile, lines);
}
```

I also use `for` instead of `foreach` in order to have an index `i`, so that I can replace a single line in the `lines` array at a specific index.

I don't know if the extension code in the directory file is unique. If it is, you can exit the for loop prematurely with `break`.